# Configure Eclipse to use HTTPS for plugin download

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-marketplace, eclipse-oxygen

Can I configure Eclipse to download plugin resources over HTTPS. Only HTTPS is allowed to download jars behind my proxy/firewall.

Also I cannot find some plugin resources to install offline or some of them requires too much work.

Answer (score 3):

HTTP/HTTPS depends on the source, if the plugin is on a server and the server is configured to host HTTPS then all is OK. Otherwise you need to have your workaround.

I would do like this:

1. **download the plugin** locally (if behind proxy, then maybe from other computer/network and store it accessible to your eclipse)
2. **install it** (either in eclipse or command line)

I find the command line plugin installation faster, you just run the eclipsec.exe and give the target where you have downloaded the plugin.

### Download from mirror/update site

Also worth to mention is if there is no plugin "full" download file, I mean sometimes you have just a update/or mirror-site url, but you can still download the plugin using:

```
eclipsec.exe
-nosplash 
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.metadata.repository.mirrorApplication 
-source url 
-destination file:your-hdd-path
```

or

```
java 
-jar plugins/org.eclipse.equinox.launcher[ECLIPSE dependent version, see ini file].jar 
-application org.eclipse.update.core.standaloneUpdate 
-command mirror 
-from url 
-to your-hdd-path
```

above differs if the plugin is on a mirror or update site. (Check if there is a site.xml file).

### Install the plugin, command line

Installation the plugin is very simple by using the command-line-version of eclipse (which ends with letter c, i.e. eclipsec), see **[Link](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_director.html)**:

```
eclipsec.exe 
-nosplash  
-application org.eclipse.equinox.p2.director 
-installIU "the-feature-to-install"
-profileProperties org.eclipse.update.install.features=true 
-profile "Your-Profil see config.ini" 
-repository "your-hdd-path" 
-destination "your-eclipse-path"
```

### Local plug-in repository

Also there is a [**dropins folder**](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Freference%2Fmisc%2Fp2_dropins_format.html&resultof=%22dropins%22%20%22dropin%22%20) in eclipse which is worth to mention, but I would go with above solution. And if you have lots of plug-ins I would recommend creating **[Composite repositories, locally](https://help.eclipse.org/oxygen/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fp2_composite_repositories.htm&resultof=%22compositeMetadataRepository%22%20%22compositemetadatarepositori%22%20)** (for other in your team to setup the plugins without web access).

Comment: Thank you for alternative download recommendations, but I cannot download over http even with eclipsec. I am able to download resources one by one over https via browser, unfortunately it is a long process. If I can force eclipse to use https first, my problem will be solved.

Comment: But can you visit the plugin url from web using https? what is the url? if the server has https enabled then there is no problem. Did you have any success with installation of any plugin at all? maybe it is this simple that you just forgot to add a proxy settings in your eclipse (see preferences network connection settings)

Comment: Can you install subclipse plugin from https source? using httpS url in eclipse https://dl.bintray.com/subclipse/releases/subclipse/latest/

Comment: Yes, I can visit url over https, proxy settings are okay. Also I was able to download other plugins. The problem is, even if I use https for update site url, eclipse tries to download some resources over http.